# Simplify expressions with constraints

Tags: simplifying-expressions

I have the following expression to simplify

$$k_1 c_1^4 + k_{12} c_1^2c_2^2 + k_2 c_2^4$$

using the conditions

$$
c_1^2 = c_{11}
$$
$$
c_2^2 = c_{22}
$$
$$
c_1 c_2 = c_{12}
$$

and I would like to write the expression above as

$$k_1 c_{11}^2 + k_{12} c_{12} + k_2 c_{22}^2$$

How can I do it with Mathematica?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way:

```
eqs = {f == k1 c1^4 + k12 c1^2 c2^2 + k2 c2^4,c1^2 == c11, c2^2 == c22, c1 c2 == c12};
Reduce[Eliminate[eqs, {c1, c2}], f]
```

> `(c22 == 0 && c12 == 0 && f == c11^2 k1) || (c22 != 0 && 
>      c11 == c12^2/c22 && f == c11^2 k1 + c12^2 k12 + c22^2 k2)`

```
Simplify[%, c22 != 0]
```

> `c12^2 == c11 c22 && f == c11^2 k1 + c12^2 k12 + c22^2 k2`

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
expr = k1 c1^4 + k12 c1^2 c2^2 + k2 c2^4;
expr /. {c1 -> Sqrt[c11], c2 -> Sqrt[c22], c1^2*c2^2 -> c12^2}

(*  c11^2 k1 + c12^2 k12 + c22^2 k2  *)
```

Have fun!

Comment: Is this right though? what if $c_1\vee c_2<0$?

Comment: @ Feyre  I see no problem in this case.

Comment: From $c_{1}^2=c_{11}$ follows $\left| c_1\right|=\sqrt{c_1}$. It's a matter of proper proof.

Comment: @Feyre  And the result of the transformation in question will be different?

Comment: Well, no. Just that I'd be cautious of doing something like that.

Comment: @Feyre  OK, this is the point. I believe you confuse it with a formal mathematical transformation. But the operation like `ReplaceAll` is different from that. Here the point is most often to find at least one replacement version that works smoothly.

Comment: That's fair enough.